# Display multiple objects from server

Tags: ios, image, webserver, refresh, displayobject

I am making an iOS app that will display images, videos, and textual information that I provide.
this information needs to be updated and refreshed as the user requests, time interval, and when the user opens the app. Not hardcoded and changed on app store updates.

How would i go about doing this?

Do I need to create an online web server that I pull the information from?

If so how would I go about creating a server?

Could anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: I think you should google first and try reading apple documentation about objective-c. We can't teach you how to code in objective-c but we can modify or provide you alternative solutions for your coding problems.

Comment: well i have coded ios applications before. I am just confused on this subject. i am not asking anyone to teach me how to code. all i am asking is a point in the correct direction which your comment was not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using parse which has excellent mobile support. And is free until you receive a certain amount of traction. I recommend it!

Answer (score 1):

yeah you have to use web Services. that means you have to create one server & from that server you can send images,text as you required without making hardcoded. you just have to pull the value from web service.

images,text all this can be send through xml  & you have to accept that xml & have to parse it

Answer (score 0):

You can install an Apache server on your MacOS, read read this:
http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/